# How to build a Docker image with the right R and package versions and open Rstudio with them afterwards?

Tags: r, docker

I just finished writing a manuscript for publication in a scientific journal. I want my research to be reproducible, so besides sharing my original and compiled R markdown notebooks on Github, I would like to save the environment in which I was analysing my data (including the data, notebooks and specific R and package versions) in a Docker container. Moreover, I would like anyone trying to reproduce my work to be able to execute this code in an interactive Rstudio session.

I was able to create a Dockerfile with the correct environment. Here is a toy example:

```
FROM rocker/r-ver:3.5.1

RUN mkdir /home/working_directory
RUN mkdir /home/working_directory/bin

RUN R -e 'options(repos = \
  list(CRAN = "http://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/2019-01-01")); \
  install.packages("ggplot2")'

COPY current/0[1-8]-*.Rmd /home/working_directory/
COPY current/bin/utils.R /home/working_directory/bin/

RUN R
```

However, this doesn't allow the users to read the Rmd notebooks and execute the code line by line. A workaround is to run the image rocker/rstudio, and install the packages from there, but I would like to be able to do so from a single docker build call. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to do so.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

The [Rocker RStudio](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/rstudio/) image should have what you need - RStudio on top R. If you want specifically R 3.5.1, you can find the source here:

- https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker-versioned/blob/master/rstudio/3.5.1/Dockerfile

For more details on how to use it read https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/rstudio.

**To just use the pre-built images with a specific R version**

```
# with R version 3.5.1:
docker pull rocker/rstudio:3.5.1
```

To investigate the image interactively:

```
docker run --rm -it rocker/rstudio:3.5.1 bash
```

Now we can run for example:

```
# Check R version
Rscript -e "sessionInfo()[['R.version']][['version.string']]"
# [1] "R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)"

# Check RStudio Server version
rstudio-server version
# 1.1.463

# Exit when done
exit
```

Comment: I've been struggling with this. Can one pull a rocker RStudio container via `docker pull rocker/rstudio` using a specific version of R? I tried `docker pull -e R_VERSION=3.2.5 rocker/rstudio` but this pulls the latest version of R, not 3.2.5.

Comment: You can simply run `docker pull rocker/rstudio:3.5.2`, [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/rstudio/tags) is a list of the available tags.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now, let's say that for reproducibility purposes I'd like to install a package from a specific snapshot of MRAN. Could I just add a line similar to that in my Dockerfile? RUN R -e options(repos = \
  list(CRAN = "http://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/2019-01-01")); \
  install.packages("tidyverse")'

Comment: This is not completely straight-forward to answer due to potential need of system dependencies, but if you are specifically looking for `tidyverse`, the good news is the Rocker project also has an image with that on top of R and R Studio: https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/tidyverse/tags. If you strictly want to manage the versions, it could be a good idea to adapt and create your own image. You can get inspiration from `r-ver` on using MRAN snapshots, e.g search for MRAN here:   https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker-versioned/blob/master/r-ver/3.2.5/Dockerfile